# postgresql: how to get the rows greater than a timestamp and also previous nearest row

Tags: postgresql

I have postgresql table with time and state

```
      time              state
2021-01-30 09:59:57+00        0
2021-01-30 09:50:36+00        1
2021-01-30 08:38:05+00        0
2021-01-30 08:29:37+00        1
2021-01-30 08:05:16+00        0
2021-01-30 07:42:27+00        1
```

i am looking for rows greater than `2021-01-30 07:45:00+00` but also want to have the nearest row before also. In this case `2021-01-30 07:42:27+00` similary w.r.t to less than

any option to include the previous one row near to the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Window variant of MAX function and union that with standard select. (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1be11551e66f7f5a9409f71162ce9a40))

```
select time_ts "Time", state  
  from test
 where time_ts >= '2021-01-30 07:45+00'::timestamp
union
Select * 
  from (select max (time_ts) over(), state
          from test
         where time_ts < '2021-01-30 07:45+00'::timestamp  
         limit 1
       ) f
order by 1;
```

---

In Reply to " `max (time_ts) over()` can you explain what it does "  
First see [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-window.html) on Window functions. Max is one of the `Aggregate` functions that also has a Window variant. Within Window functions the Over(...) builds groups (partitions) within row set selected, using `Over()` clause creates a single group over the entire row set. The advantage here is that is avoids the "Group By" required by the standard aggregate (which could produce multiple rows).  While selecting a single row it will select the same row for each row in the result set thus the limit 1. You can see this with the following:

```
select time_ts, max(time_ts) over() from test;
```

Note: You used TIME as a column name, but that is a valid Postgres data type. I do not use data types as column names. I get confused over talking about the column or the data type.

Comment: ` max (time_ts) over()` can you explain what it does

Comment: Update answer to include explanation.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same to use `ORDER BY time_ts DESC LIMIT 1` as the second element to the UNION? If there's an index on `time_ts` the ordering would be an (fast) index operation.
Also, isn't there a way to do it in one piece, I mean, without doing `UNION` or anything like that?